# SVN Respository Structure

Tags: svn

My company is about to switch to using svn and i am looking for advice on repository structure.

We currently have around 10 projects and a store of in-house common software which some of the projects use and some don't. As the common software is modfied in house it is a project in its own right. So although the projects are unrelated they may share the same common software.

Projects that use the common software always refer to a baselined version i.e. common software is never modified under any project (apart from the common software project itself).

So would seperate repositories for each project be the best, with the common software project "tagged" version being hooked in using svn:externals?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to put everything in one repos according to the first example in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.planning.html. The COMMON would be one project along all the others.

Then you copy release tags of the COMMON to each project, reflecting the version of the COMMON that each project is currently using.

Example layout:

```
/common
  /branches
    /common_improvements1
    /common_improvements2
  /tags
    /common-1.0.0
    /common-1.0.1
  /trunk
/projA
  /branches
    /stable-1.0
      /common (=copy of /projA/trunk@oldrev =copy of /common/tags/common-1.0.0)
    /stable-2.0
      /common (=copy of /projA/trunk@somerev =copy of /common/tags/common-1.0.1)
    /projA_ongoing_fix_branch
  /tags
    /1.0.1
    /1.0.2
    /1.1.0
    /2.0.0
    /2.0.1
  /trunk
    /common (=copy of /common/tags/common-1.0.1)
/projB
  (similar structures)
/projC
  (similar structures)
```

Benefits:

1. easy access and traceability between COMMON and projects
2. if useful, user's can easily interact, test, and support each others efforts
3. the copies of COMMON release tags answers the question: Which version of the COMMON are we currently using in this project?

Optional step during import:

Do you have a common layout for all the projects today, e.g. a file structure on a server, or another version control system? If so, I recommend you to:

1. import the entire layout to a folder in the new repository, e.g. /root/old_layout
2. move the project files and folders into the new layout, inside the svn repos

This has the benefit that the revision log answer the question: Where was this file in our previous structure? This can be very useful while teaching the developers the new structure, and if temporary resources (e.g. consultants) comes back after the layout change.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful!
This is an ideal structure and would work for us.
My only query on this is about having copies of the common software in each project.
Our current common software repositories (or VOBS, as we are switching from clearcase) are quite large (up to 1GB). So having duplicated copies in each project may quickly eat up server disk and affect performance?

Comment: By using copies of the COMMON release tags in each project do you mean an actual copy or is their any smart way of using links - I have heard of SVN external for this purpose but have also read some bad press about them. Also, with the company being new to SVN would much prefer to adopt the simplest solution initially!

Comment: All copies in a svn repos are smart links so the copies of the release tags will only add a marginal amount of link information to your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Will all the developers work on all projects? Or will each developer work on a specific project only?

If the former I would consider having each project as a branch (as switching between branches is easier than switching between repositories). You can also create new branches very easily for new projects.

If the latter then separate repos is probably cleaner and easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks. Each developer will work on a specific project. So i am hoping that when they connect to the project repository they will see that Project X as a top level folder and COMMON which will contain external links to the common software required for that project. Maybe use export for COMMON as it should not be modified under that project?

Comment: if you want projectX to be the top level using separate repos for each project will achieve that. There's allsorts of pre-commit options depending on how much you want to lock down the COMMON, but that's down to personal preference/how much you trust your devs ;)

Answer (score 0):

don't use separate repositories, put it all in one (SVN can handle very large repos quite happily). This would give you benefits in sharing your common code and branching in future.

The difference is really just an extra "directory" at the top level anyway. The benefit is less maintenance and easier access.